# email body coming in a single line

Tags: c#

I am sending emails thorugh c#. The body of the mail is dynamic i.e. user fills it in before sending the mail. Issue is the body text is coming in a single line instead of multiple lines as they should.

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtEmail.Text.Trim(), email.Trim()))
{
    try
    {
        mm.CC.Add(txtcc.Text.Trim());
        mm.Subject = txtSubject.Text.Trim();

        mm.Body = txtBody.Text;
        MemoryStream pdf = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(pdf, "Report.pdf"));
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;              
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
        credentials.UserName = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
        credentials.Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = credentials;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Alert.show1("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message, this);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to put in line breaks /r/n for new line.

Comment: @AliK I didn't get you!! where to put likne breaks in it   mm.Body = txtBody.Text;

Comment: Use this: `mm.Body = "First Line <br /> second line";`. You can replace `\n` to `<br />`

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi I have multiple lines, do we have another method for this

Comment: As mentioned you can put /r/n in between lines where you want to have a new line and i would suggest stringbuilder to build the message.

Comment: @TanviDutta `txtBody.Text` is muliple line?

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi yes

Comment: You set `IsBodyHtml` to true. So _is_ it HTML? If so, then it does not matter whether it is in one line. The client will render `<br />` to new lines again. If it is actually plain text, then you should either send as plain text or "htmlify" the content by replacing newlines with `<br />` (and probably ensure it is valid html)

Comment: "do we have another method for this?" In my honest opinion, having a method for a simple `.Replace(@"\n", @"<br />")` is overkill.

Comment: I'd also recommend to add an alternateView in plain text for clients that are not html capable.

Comment: thank you @Fildor, solved my issue

Comment: @TanviDutta You could also send the email in plain text, check my answer that takes into account both options.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the potential of HTML formatting, you could avoid the problem changing the email format to plain text. This could also avoid user entering text that could be parsed as html.

```
mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
```

Otherwise you should change the end line character to html breaking line:

```
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
mm.Body = mm.Body.Replace(@"\n", "<br />");
```

In case of the html format option, It would be wise to follow Fildor's comment and add an `alternateView` in plain text for email clients that are not html capable.